# How to read certain GEO files with Bio.Geo?

Tags: python, parsing, bioinformatics, biopython

I am trying to parse a GEO file with Bio.Geo according to the tutorial in the following way:

```
from Bio import Geo
handle = open('GSE40603_combined_L1_L2.txt')
records = Geo.parse(handle)
for record in records:
    print record
```

But I get a following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/spyderlib/widgets/externalshell/sitecustomize.py", line 585, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)
  File "/home/ilya/Документы/biology/E coli GCC/GEOanalyzer.py", line 11, in <module>
    for record in records:
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Bio/Geo/__init__.py", line 60, in parse
    record.table_rows.append(row)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'table_rows'
```

Here is the head of that file:

```
0   0   63  NC_000913   0   152 NC_000913   0   152 |neigh_up NC_000913-start |neigh_down CDS[fcd=114](+,190,255) gene= thrL    |neigh_up NC_000913-start |neigh_down CDS[fcd=114](+,190,255) gene= thrL  
0   1   81  NC_000913   0   152 NC_000913   153 599 |neigh_up NC_000913-start |neigh_down CDS[fcd=114](+,190,255) gene= thrL    |gene gene= thrL  |CDS(+,190,255) gene= thrL  |gene gene= thrA  |CDS(+,337,2799) gene= thrA  note= bifunctional: aspartokinase I (N-terminal); 
0   2   1   NC_000913   0   152 NC_000913   600 698 |neigh_up NC_000913-start |neigh_down CDS[fcd=114](+,190,255) gene= thrL    |gene gene= thrA  |CDS[fcd=-312](+,337,2799) gene= thrA  note= bifunctional: aspartokinase I (N-terminal); 
0   3   1   NC_000913   0   152 NC_000913   699 755 |neigh_up NC_000913-start |neigh_down CDS[fcd=114](+,190,255) gene= thrL    |gene gene= thrA  |CDS[fcd=-390](+,337,2799) gene= thrA  note= bifunctional: aspartokinase I (N-terminal); 
0   4   1   NC_000913   0   152 NC_000913   756 757 |neigh_up NC_000913-start |neigh_down CDS[fcd=114](+,190,255) gene= thrL    |gene gene= thrA  |CDS[fcd=-419](+,337,2799) gene= thrA  note= bifunctional: aspartokinase I (N-terminal); 
0   2620    1   NC_000913   0   152 NC_000913   352429  352483  |neigh_up NC_000913-start |neigh_down CDS[fcd=114](+,190,255) gene= thrL    |gene gene= prpE  |CDS[fcd=-526](+,351930,353816) gene= prpE  note= putative propionyl-CoA synthetase  
0   18818   1   NC_000913   0   152 NC_000913   2560323 2560384 |neigh_up NC_000913-start |neigh_down CDS[fcd=114](+,190,255) gene= thrL    |misc_feature note= cryptic prophage Eut/CPZ-55  |gene gene= yffO  |CDS[fcd=-220](+,2560133,2560549) gene= yffO  
0   2617    1   NC_000913   0   152 NC_000913   352326  352375  |neigh_up NC_000913-start |neigh_down CDS[fcd=114](+,190,255) gene= thrL    |gene gene= prpE  |CDS[fcd=-420](+,351930,353816) gene= prpE  note= putative propionyl-CoA synthetase  
0   18817   1   NC_000913   0   152 NC_000913   2560275 2560322 |neigh_up NC_000913-start |neigh_down CDS[fcd=114](+,190,255) gene= thrL    |misc_feature note= cryptic prophage Eut/CPZ-55  |gene gene= yffO  |CDS[fcd=-165](+,2560133,2560549) gene= yffO  
0   912 1   NC_000913   0   152 NC_000913   113055  113082  |neigh_up NC_000913-start |neigh_down CDS[fcd=114](+,190,255) gene= thrL    |gene gene= coaE  |CDS[fcd=151](-,112599,113219) gene= coaE  note= putative DNA repair protein
```

Am I doing something wrong? How do I read such files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This file is a so-called "supplemental file" from GEO.  It was supplied by the original submitter, so tools to read GEO formats will not work with it.

In this particular case, your best bet is to simply parse your downloaded file with standard python tools.

Comment: Thank you, @seandavi! This is all new to me.